# How to auto indent JSP files using JDT ?

Tags: java, jsp, indentation, eclipse-jdt

I am using JDT to auto indent my code. This indents Java code but it does not indent the JSP code... I get NullPointerException when I try to indent JSP code with JDT.

Please suggest a JAVA CODE to indent JSP files.

Following code I am using for indentation:

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.eclipse.jface.text.BadLocationException;

import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ToolFactory;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.CodeFormatter;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.DefaultCodeFormatterConstants;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.Document;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;
import org.eclipse.text.edits.MalformedTreeException;
import org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEdit;

public class Indenter {

    CodeFormatter codeFormatter;

    public Indenter() {
        // take default Eclipse formatting options
        Map<String, String> options = DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.getEclipseDefaultSettings();

        // initialize the compiler settings to be able to format 1.5 code
        options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_COMPLIANCE, JavaCore.VERSION_1_7);
        options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_CODEGEN_TARGET_PLATFORM, JavaCore.VERSION_1_7);
        options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_SOURCE, JavaCore.VERSION_1_7);

        // change the option to wrap each enum constant on a new line
        options.put(DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.FORMATTER_ALIGNMENT_FOR_ENUM_CONSTANTS,
                DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.createAlignmentValue(true, 
                        DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.WRAP_ONE_PER_LINE,
                        DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.INDENT_ON_COLUMN));

        // instantiate the default code formatter with the given options
        codeFormatter = ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(options);
    }

    public String indent(String source, String language){

        if("JAVA".equalsIgnoreCase(language)){
            final TextEdit edit = codeFormatter.format(
                CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT, // format a compilation unit
                source, // source to format
                0, // starting position
                source.length(), // length
                0, // initial indentation
                System.getProperty("line.separator") // line separator
            );

            IDocument document = new Document(source);
            try {
                edit.apply(document);
                return document.get();
            } catch (BadLocationException | MalformedTreeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return source;
    }
}
```